# Проблема с принятием лицензии для утилиты TFVC

Tags: java, c#, rider

Для работы с TFVC в Rider необходима утилита TEE-CLC. А для ее работы необходимо сначала принять лицензионное соглашение. Установил последний JAVA SDK 9.0.1, установил все системные переменные:

- JAVA_HOME = "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\"
- JRE_HOME = "c:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\"
- CLASSPATH =.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JRE_HOME%\lib
- добавил %JAVA_HOME%\bin в PATH

После этого в папке с утилитой TEE-CLC в коммандном окне запускаю комманду tf eula /accept. И ничего не происходит. Пару секунд думает и возвращается к строке приглашения.

Где может быть проблема?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась до смешного просто - сносом 9-й версии и установкой 8-й версии Java, ну или официальной SDK версии 1.8.u161. После этого все заработало.